# Find Multiple Places Types Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to fetch nearby places and show data in a list using Google Places API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&key=key&location=location&radius=radius&types=type

I am getting the response. But to my understanding
multiple types(atm,airport,restaurants) in single request is now deprecated by google.

So to move forward to get all the prominent places near me what is the best approach?